# 16 digit timestamp to Java date format

Tags: java, date, timestamp, type-conversion

I have a 16 digit timestamp from a app I cannot se into.

I would like to use it in Java application.

Is there a function that allows you to make such conversion?

Example:

1409304572565675 is 29 August 2014 11:29

I found out it might be a php milisecond timestamp but can't find any way to convert it to date in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it *really is* milliseconds since epoch (Jan 1st 1970 00:00:000 GMT) you'd just call `new Date(1409304572565675L)`.

However, that seems to be a microsecond timestamp, i.e. you'd have to devide that by 1000 to get actual milliseconds, so `new Date(1409304572565675L / 1000)` would be your way to go.

Comment: Yes, it was in microseconds: new Date(1409304572565675L / 1000) is perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this `System.out.println(new Date(1409304572565675L/1000 ));`
Dont forget about timezone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **setTimeInMillis()** method on a ***Calendar*** object:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeInMillis(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Long.parseLong:

```
String x = "1086073200000"

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

long milliSeconds= Long.parseLong(x);
System.out.println(milliseconds);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
System.out.println(formatter.format(calendar.getTime()));
```